# How to check which timer is running in jquery.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am using easytimer (https://github.com/albert-gonzalez/easytimer.js) and I got into an issue.
I create multiple timer on one page, each timer has its own start and stop button.
Now I want to make sure there is only one timer running at the same time.
So I imagine if I click start button of timer 3, it should check all other timers if they are running then stop them.

Below is my code

```js
        $('tr.step').each(function (index) {
            var timer = new easytimer.Timer();

            btnStart.off('click').on('click', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (timer.isRunning()) {
                    console.log(timer + index + 'is running');
                }
                timer.start({
                    callback: function (timer) {
                        valTimer.html(
                            timer.getTimeValues().toString()
                        );
                    }
                });
                btnStart.hide();
                btnStop.fadeIn(1000);
            });

            btnStop.off('click').on('click', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                timer.stop();
            });
```

So anyone please help me how to check which timer is running and stop it before start counting a new one.

Comment: Push the `.Timer()` return into an array defined outside the `.each` so you can access them all when you want to stop.  `var timers = [];` ... `timers.push(new easytimer.Timer());`.   Also, if you have one btnStart/btnStop then move those click event handlers *outside* the `each` loop otherwise you only get the last one.

Comment: That nice, I use an array and have solve the problem 
But when I push `var lblStep = $(this).find('td.no div.symbol');` to an array and call a function removeClass in array, it say removeClass is not a function `val.lblStep.removeClass('symbol-light-warning');`